# Raspberry PI B+ GPIO not responding

Tags: gpio, python

I'm still a beginner, but I can't make heads or tails of this.  My new Raspberry PI B+ GPIO pins don't seem to be actually changing when I run python code essentially straight from the web.  Am I doing something wrong?

**Code**

I'm running this as root on Raspbian after a fresh update/upgrade/reboot.  It's plugged in with the packaged power supply (nothing special or custom).

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

target = 5

def blink(pin):
    GPIO.output(pin, True)
    time.sleep(1)

    GPIO.output(pin, False)
    time.sleep(1)
    return

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(target, GPIO.OUT)

for i in range(0, 20):
    blink(target)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

**Circuit**

I've tried this six ways to Sunday; changing target pins, running as BCM or BOARD mode, anything I can think of.  You can see here the light is on when the script isn't running, which I found odd.  When I ran this script on GPIO 6, the light started off and stayed off.
[image: My basic circuit]

Anyone know what else I should try?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't you init the port before use it? Just a guess ...

Comment: The code looks all right (BCM is correct when using gpio numbers) and the wiring looks all right.  Are you sure the ribbon cable isn't back to front on the Pi.  Measure the voltage on the breadboard 5V rail.

Comment: I'll try the init when I get home today, but the ribbon is properly configured (I tested other 3.3v/5v ports, plus the rails on the sides).

Comment: @Goldilocks; you were correct.  I had the same problems as the other user/thread.  The ribbon was reversed (wrong pins) and the LED was flipped.  Same kit- go figure, eh?